# What is the format of the packet header when using netfilter queues?

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

I'm using netfilter queues on Ubuntu 14.10.  Everything is working so far, I'm seeing packets and setting the verdict, but I'd like to get a better idea of what I'm reading from the queue.

Starting from this [page](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html).

This is the code in question:

```
fd = nfq_fd(h);
while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) >= 0)
{
    printf("pkt received\n");
    nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
}
```

At the point where they have a `printf()`, what exactly has been read from fd?  I assume it is the packet preceeded by some kind of netfilter-specific header, but I have no idea what that header would be.  I'm looking at a dump of the bytes I'm reading, but I'm not seeing a valid L2, L3, nor L4 anywhere in there.

Note that as per the documentation, I did setup the queue in copy mode with this line:

```
nfq_set_mode(qh, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like netfilter queues returns L3+.  There is no L2.  When the callback is running -- called by [nfq_handle_packet()](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/netfilter/group__Queue.html#ga593b576017b7423646f49558a39f4ee5) -- what I'm seeing is 58 bytes of <something> (not L2) followed by L3.

The ethertype from the "missing" L2 can be obtained using:

```
struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *ph = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfad);
const uint32_t id = ntohl(ph->packet_id);
const uint16_t ethertype = ntohs(ph->hw_protocol);
```

Then L3 is obtained with:

```
uint8_t *payload_data = nullptr;
const int payload_len = nfq_get_payload(nfad, &payload_data);
```

If needed, the source MAC address from L2 may be available with a call to [nfq_get_packet_hw()](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/netfilter/group__Parsing.html#ga8db3aa65f17cca3ea07c50994524c160).